# c++ virtual function reimplementation

Tags: c++, oop, function, virtual

even i think that question is stupid. but i've a little experience.

i have a base class that has such method:

```
class A{  virtual void func(int)=0 };
```

and inherited class

```
    class  B :public A
  {  
     //how should i write?
    //a  
       virtual void func() {    implementation...}  

    //b
      void func() {implementation    } 
   //my target is to redefine a function of ansestor
 //i worry that variant b can  cover ansestor function and i will not redefine it
 //but what if i don't want that the function that was virtual in ansestor, will   be      virtual in subclass? 
i'm confused
}
```

i don't know that to do. if i don't need this virtual function complete

Comment: do you have a book on C++? This kind of questions can be answered by reading through chapters devoted to "inheritance".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by making the redefined function non-virtual?

Comment: The virtual keyword is optional in the derived class, so you are defining the same function twice.

Comment: He's asking whether `virtual` is required when overriding the function. He's worried that omitting the keyword in the derived class might hide the ancestor function. But if it doesn't hide the function, then he wonders, what if he really *did* want to hide it with a non-virtual function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask, "what if i don't want that the function that was virtual in ansestor, will be virtual in subclass?"

Sorry, but every function that is declared `virtual` in a base class, is also virtual in all derived classes.

It actually doesn't matter whether you use the `virtual` keyword in the derived-class declaration. Options a and b are identical -- in both cases `B::func` is virtual.

Comment: Yet, use virtual only if you intend to redefine this function in a derived class, it make your code more understandable.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest your write two small programs, one for each implementation to determine which suits your needs.

Comment: Huh? It doesn't matter whether `virtual` is included on `B::func`. They're equivalent definitions.

Comment: I think it would just cause confusion because both programs would work the same. That would just prompt more questions for someone who's clearly already confused.

Comment: Well, I guess we can disagree.  I think it would help in addition to what you say it just does.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the function signature consists of the function name and function arguments. In a class you cannot have two functions with same signature. So your second (non-virtual) function declaration will generate compiler errors.

In short:

```
virtual void func() { //implementation}
```

and

```
void func() { //implementation }
```

have the same signature and cannot be declared in the same class.

Comment: I don't think he wanted to have *both* in the same class. "My target is to redefine a function of ansestor." He wanted to know which of those two ways was correct.

Comment: I guess you are right, He was not very clear in his description.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual means that reimplementation is possible in inherited class(es). Virtual function will allways be virtual no matter the depth of inheritance.